# How to group data and display data in nested Xib in UITableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview, xib

I am using two Xib files in a tableView. One is `Main Xib` and second is `ChildView Xib.`
I am fetching data from SQLite and already data is placed in my two models.

In Main Header Xib I am already displaying date which is `appdate` in `mDownloadEntity`.

But I want to display same date once (not repeating) and in ChildView `projectName` which is a part of Appointment.

I have tried to use for Loop but it not correct way and not working.

- In attached image Sqlite DB -  Date columns has 4 same dates(stored as `Int64`) but
  different appointmentId and appointmentDownloadModel. So I want to
  display one date in MainHeader and 4 Appointments - projectName in
  ChildView
- 1589317200000 is 13May2020 has 4 appointments.

```
var mAppointmentDownloadModel: [AppointmentDownloadModel] = []
var mDownloadEntity: [DownloadEntity] = []
```

Model:

```
struct AppointmentDownloadModel: Codable{
    var appointmentModel: Appointment
    var progress: Int = 0
    var failedList: [Int: String] = [:]
    var isFinished: Bool = false
}

struct DownloadEntity: Codable {

    let id: Int
    var appdate: Int64
    var userId: Int
    var dFirmId: Int
    var appointmentId: Int
    var appointmentDownloadModel: AppointmentDownloadModel?
}

struct Appointment : Codable {

    let date : String?
    let id : Int?
    let projectName : String?
    let projectType : String?
}
```

TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadEntryViewCell
        let dic = mDownloadEntity[indexPath.row]
        var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0


        let appDate = Date(milliseconds: dic.appdate)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy EEEE"
        let convertDate = dateFormatter.string(from: appDate)

        cell.fileNameLabel.text = "\(convertDate)"


        // ChildView
        for i in mAppointmentDownloadModel {

            let child_view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FooterView
            print(i.appointmentModel.projectName)
            child_view.projName.text = i.appointmentModel.projectName

            cell.stackViewFooter.addArrangedSubview(child_view)
            stackHeight = stackHeight + 0

         }

        return cell
    }
```

SQLite DB Query - Adding Elements to model:

```
let query = downloadTable.select(download_id, download_date, user_id, dFirmid, appoint_id, appoint_model).order(download_date.desc)
let result = try db?.prepare(query)

for i in result! {
    let primaryId = i[download_id]
   let dd = i[download_date]
   let userId = i[user_id]
   let firmId = i[dFirmid]
   let apId = i[appoint_id]
   let appModel = i[appoint_model]

    print(i)

    let dataa = Data(appModel.utf8)
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(AppointmentDownloadModel.self, from: dataa)
    print(res)

    let appDataModel = AppointmentDownloadModel(appointmentModel: res.appointmentModel, progress: res.progress, failedList: res.failedList, isFinished: res.isFinished)

    mDownloadEntity.append(DownloadEntity(id: Int(primaryId), appdate: dd, userId: Int(userId), dFirmId: Int(firmId), appointmentId: apId, appointmentDownloadModel: appDataModel ))

    print("Final Data: \(mDownloadEntity)")
}
```

SQLite DB Image:
[image: DB]

Comment: You want to group the appointments by date? Arrange your datasource so that a given date is a section I.e that section/date will have 4 items.

Comment: @WarrenBurton  Yes I want to group appointments by date and date to be display in Header which is `cell` and `projectName` in childView so 1 group date displays 4 in childView Xib.

Comment: In which way are you adding elements to the mAppointmentDownloadModel array?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro I have updated, please check on `SQLite DB Query - Adding Elements to model` section.